# Имеет ли смысл инкапсуляция и превращение в свойство атрибута без какой-либо валидации в setter?

Tags: python, ооп, инкапсуляция

На данный момент при получении значения из базы данных (которое может быть любым, ну или например мы точно знаем, что оно будет корректным), данное значение устанавливается в атрибут класса. Атрибут публичен.

Стоит ли делать его приватным, создавая публичное свойство с геттером и сеттером, если в сеттере не будет никаких валидирующих операций по принимаемому значению? Какой в этом смысл?

Answer (score 1):

Это поощрение ответственности программистов, в том числе и валидация данных, которые передаются в переменную.

Также, никто не останавливает вас следовать PEP8 и делать поля класса "приватными", используя двойное нижнее подчеркивание

```py
class MyType():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value_public = value
        self.__value = value
    def set_value(self, value):
        self.__value = value
    def get_value(self):
        return self.__value
```

В данном случае при обращении к переменной `__value`, как к полю вы получите ошибку

```py
>>> m = MyType(10) 
>>> m.__value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'MyType' object has no attribute '__value'
```

Но при этом `get`-метод отработает как и положено

```py
>>> m.get_value()
10
```

И все это время "публичная" переменная доступна без ограничений

```py
>>> m.value_public
10
```

Стоит ли делать поля приватными? Возвращаясь к первому тезису - это ваша ответственность, как программиста и все зависит от конкретной задачи. Инкапсуляция в `python` работает лишь на уровне соглашения между программистами о том, какие атрибуты являются общедоступными, а какие — внутренними. Почему на уровне соглашения и почему я использую кавычки для определения "приватный"? Потому, что если сильно захотеть, то доступ к приватному полю можно получить, например так

```py
>>> m._MyType__value
10
```

На счет валидации, не стоит забывать, что `python` имеет динамическую типизацию и это вносит некие свободы и ограничения для программистов. Да, можно строго определить тип переменной как в `__init__` методе, так и `set`, используя условия и/или исключения. Но  python тем и хорош, что основные операции для типов данных уже определены и мы можем переопределять стандартные методы в своем классе. Например, для арифметических операций `__add__()`, `__sub__()`, `__mul__()`, которые будут работать для числовых типов данных и стоит ли строго типизировать ваше поле - это ваша отвественность.

И можно использовать аннтоации, которые подсказывают какие данные должны передаваться в метод и какие мы получаем на выходе. Хотя тут я встречаю посетителей, которые не очень жалуют этот функционал

```py
class MyType():
    def __init__(self, value:int) -> None:
        self.value_public = value
        self.__value = value
    def set_value(self, value:int):
        self.__value = value
    def get_value(self) -> int:
        return self.__value
     

m = MyType(10)  
m.__init__.__annotations__
# OUT
# {'value': <class 'int'>, 'return': None}
```